# blazor change value on javascript call

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I'm using javascript library that fires an event on user interaction (click on element produced by the js library). In javascript i'm subscribed to this event and i'm able to handle it.
Then, this event has a input parameter and i need data from server based on it. This data is populated on DOM and that works fine. Example :

```
    function onClick(e) {
        $('#countryName').text(e.name);

        DotNet.invokeMethodAsync('Blazor', 'GetCountryInformation', e.name)
            .then(message => {
                $('#countryInfo').text(message);
            });
    }
```

Server method GetCountryInformation :

```
[JSInvokable]
public static Task GetCountryInformation(string selectedCountry)
{
    string result = MyService.GetCompanyInfo(selectedCountry);
    ParaContent = result;
    return Task.FromResult(result);
}
```

The thing is that i want to update value of ParaContent at that time and this doesn't work (value on the UI is just not changed - @ParaContent is just in span), most probably because ParaContent is defined as static. Otherwise i'm receiving an error :

```
An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property
```

I believe the problem is with static definition , but if i define the server method without static it's not hit and i have an error :

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: System.ArgumentException: The assembly 'Blazor' does not contain a public invokable method with [JSInvokableAttribute("GetCountryInformation")]
```

Is it possible at all ? Or i should change the approach somehow ? Thanks ..

Answer (score 0):

You are currently using the static C# method technique.

If you want to consume `ParaContent` in a class/component then you need to use the class/component instance technique.

You can see explanation on how to do this in the MSDocs here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/javascript-interoperability/call-dotnet-from-javascript?view=aspnetcore-5.0#component-instance-net-method-helper-class-1

You will probably need to call `StateHasChanged` in the handler to cause a UI refresh to update the display of `ParaContent`.

Comment: StateHasChanged cannot be used in static method. Provided example doesn't really fit my needs

Comment: So how are you consuming `ParaContent`? Can you put the code in the question.  I', assuming the click event is on a map or other visual display rather than a text control.

Comment: <span>@ParaContent</span>

Comment: As interaction with components is on instances, if you can't change your JsInterop from a static to an instance then your stuck.  There's no safe way to call an instance method from a static method.